# Moving a RavenDB 3.5 database to a new drive, same server - format for relative path for DataDir?

Tags: ravendb

We began using RavenDB with the data on the C drive of our servers. Now we want to move the databases (not the software) to the D drive.

I know the procedure for how to do move it but don't know how to update the DataDir property in the System db. I've tried:

D:\RavenDatabases

D://RavenDatabases

Neither one works. Found a posting that said the path was relative to the System database, but how do I move the System db along with the data db and then update the DataDir property?

Answer (score 1):

So there is very little information online about how to move a db between drives.

What I was able to piece together is:

- Stop IIS or the app pool that Raven is running under
- Disable each db (from the gear icon Takedowns)
- Create a new directory on another drive and give the app pool user Modify permissions to it
- Move the folders via the file system
- Update the web.config of the RavenDB web site to point to the new database folder
- Make sure to look at each db and fix any corrupt indices

This process is not optimal, but it worked. We only have 11 separate dbs right now so it wasn't too bad.